# How to eliminate this error while installing the sas enterprise miner for language?

Tags: sas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX8Lq.png)

I changed my system language settings and Uni-Code.I am only having the sasenterpriseminer.exe file. Are there any settings which needs to be changed. I am using windows 11 and i am installing the software on my ACER Nitro 5 laptop.

Comment: This sounds like something SAS Tech Support should be able to help with.